# Creating a vector of players and adding information to each

Tags: c++, vector

I am creating a monopoly game that allows 1-6 players to play (if you choose one then you'll go up against an AI). I created a vector

```
vector <int> players;
```

and have asked for the user to enter how many players are playing

```
    int numplayers =0 ;
vector <int> players(numplayers);

cout << "How many players will be playing this round of Monopoly? 1-6" << endl;
cin >> numplayers;
```

}

after the user indicates how many players are playing I need to have each player choose a game piece and then display their game piece, amount of money, eventually properties owned etc.

I'm wondering how I can move through chosen number of players in the vector and assign each the entered information.

Any information would be very helpful.

Comment: An integer is not the right type of data to store a whole player class.  If you are just trying to store the number of players playing though, then a plain `int` without the vector is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend creating a class Player, add attributes to the players based on user input, and then store them in the vector players. This will also be more flexible for future changes, imo.

Comment: Thank you for the answer...would it be okay to ask how I would store that information into the vector players

Comment: You would create a class Player, and then create a vector<Player>, instead of vector<int>.  To make a class, you'd write class Player{ .... } in one of your header files, and then put members into the class which you care about. I'd recommend reading up on object-oriented programming to learn more

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/ is documentation on classes in C++.

Comment: @K.Camp If this has answered your question, please 'accept' the answer.